# Keep RecyclerView item expanded after fragment transition

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, fragment, expand

I have A `RecyclerView` with items that can be expanded.
When the item is expanded the user is able to tap on some of its content which will redirect him to another fragment.

When I go `popBackStack()` from that fragment I want to keep that selected item expanded but instead all of them are collapsed

Any ideas?

Comment: hmm, save that position of the list in shared pref, and when you are coming back to this screen, use    View view = mRecyclerView.getChildAt(your position) and                     ListView  listview = view.findViewById(R.id.listview); and listview.showVisibility(VISIBLE) where listview works as expanded area

Answer (score 0):

You can introduce another boolean property in your item data. Let's say `isExpanded` which by default can be `false`. Have a callback listener for item expand and then you set the new property `isExpanded` to `true`. And in `onBindViewHolder` you can check for this property in the item and accordingly expand or collapse your item view.